# MasterCard Payment Gateway API Single Page App

Tags: javascript, api, single-page-application, mastercard

I am using the Mastercard Payment Gateway API for Hosted Session: [Mastercard Payment Gateway API Documentation](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/session/version/34/api.html?locale=en_US)

The integration works as expected on the first load but this has been written into a single page app. When the user goes back a page via the breadcrumbs (using javascript hash to load 'pages'). When the user then returns to the payment 'page' the Mastercard payment api should then be triggered a second time, this does not happen.

The documentation doesn't say if `PaymentSession.configure({})` can be sent more than once but I am assuming that is my issue.

I have tried to 'reset' the `PaymentSession` and reload the `session.js` javascript but so far have not been able to get this particular case working. I was wondering if there is a way to 'reset' the `configure()` or if there was another way to approach this?

I would rather not copy and paste my code in as it's a payment integration although it's pretty much line for line the same as the example on the documentation. I would also say that the issue is unrelated my personal code and more towards how Mastercard's Payment API works and the fact that my website is a single page rather than only loading session.js when needed.

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like it when the answer is given by the op, but I have a solution:

```
$.getScript("<mastercard url + version + merchant id>/session.js", function() { 
  //PaymentSession && PaymentSession.configure(); 
});
```

This uses jQuery to load `session.js` every time the single page payment hash is called. Once the MasterCard payment script has been executed it then runs the `PaymentSession.configure()`.

My company will be eventually moving away from the MasterCard payment api so this is a suitable solution and doesn't add too much to the page load.
I would still be very interested in learning whether or not this script can be reset another way.

Comment: Hi@TomFirth can you please help me for master card payment gateway integration in ionic 3 based application ?

Comment: how can we use this in Android? https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html   may be from webview? can you refer me the github samples with js html files!! there no native sdk available for android!!

Comment: Hi, Can you helpme to figerout how to get session id .

Comment: Hi Please can you help me with the Pay using session id?

Comment: @MunawarHussian Have you found how it is achieved from PaymentSession in Session.js? The doc only show sample with REST API, which hits CORS issue!

Answer (score 0):

install jquery first then do this in your component

```
declare const PaymentSession: any;

$.getScript(
        <"mastercard url/version/merchantId>/session.js",
        function () {
            if (PaymentSession) {
                PaymentSession.configure({
                    fields: {
                        // ATTACH HOSTED FIELDS TO YOUR PAYMENT PAGE FOR A CREDIT CARD
                        card: {
                            number: "#card-number",
                            securityCode: "#security-code",
                            expiryMonth: "#expiry-month",
                            expiryYear: "#expiry-year",
                            nameOnCard: "#cardholder-name",
                        },
                    },
                    session: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    //SPECIFY YOUR MITIGATION OPTION HERE
                    frameEmbeddingMitigation: ["javascript"],
                    callbacks: {
                        initialized: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);

                            // HANDLE INITIALIZATION RESPONSE
                        },
                        formSessionUpdate: function (response) {
                            // HANDLE RESPONSE FOR UPDATE SESSION
                            if (response.status) {
                                if ("ok" == response.status) {
                                    console.log(
                                        "Session updated with data: " +
                                            response.session.id
                                    );

                                    //check if the security code was provided by the user
                                    if (
                                        response.sourceOfFunds.provided.card
                                            .securityCode
                                    ) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "Security code was provided."
                                        );
                                    }

                                    //check if the user entered a Mastercard credit card
                                    if (
                                        response.sourceOfFunds.provided.card
                                            .scheme == "MASTERCARD"
                                    ) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "The user entered a Mastercard credit card."
                                        );
                                    }
                                } else if (
                                    "fields_in_error" == response.status
                                ) {
                                    console.log(
                                        "Session update failed with field errors."
                                    );
                                    if (response.errors.cardNumber) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "Card number invalid or missing."
                                        );
                                    }
                                    if (response.errors.expiryYear) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "Expiry year invalid or missing."
                                        );
                                    }
                                    if (response.errors.expiryMonth) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "Expiry month invalid or missing."
                                        );
                                    }
                                    if (response.errors.securityCode) {
                                        console.log(
                                            "Security code invalid."
                                        );
                                    }
                                } else if (
                                    "request_timeout" == response.status
                                ) {
                                    console.log(
                                        "Session update failed with request timeout: " +
                                            response.errors.message
                                    );
                                } else if (
                                    "system_error" == response.status
                                ) {
                                    console.log(
                                        "Session update failed with system error: " +
                                            response.errors.message
                                    );
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log(
                                    "Session update failed: " + response
                                );
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    interaction: {
                        displayControl: {
                            formatCard: "EMBOSSED",
                            invalidFieldCharacters: "REJECT",
                        },
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    );
```